# After activating Maven plugin: location of java files changed, servlet 3.0 not working anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

i had a normal Eclipse (Mars) dynamic web project and after i activated M2e plugin yesterday my servlet cannot be found when making a http get request. First, all my java files somehow where moved to another location within the project (from "Java Resources/(packageName)/..." to "src/com/(projectName)". I tried to add that folder to the Build path source, and now it seems like it´s in the correct location again, but the servlet mapping still won´t work.

This is how my project structure looks right now:

[image: project structure]

So on the right you see the name ("Test") and mapping Path ("/Test") of my 3.0 servlet. It is also shown in the deployment descriptor.

When i load my page in the browser via "http://localhost:8080/Webmap/" the page is loaded normally, but when i want to query my servlet via ajax i get a 404 error. How can i make this work again?

Edit: This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Webmap_read</groupId>
  <artifactId>Webmap_read</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>ClimateCharts</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: Thanks for asking. It didn´t work somehow, so I just created a new maven project and copied the java/javscript/css files. now it is working.

Comment: okay - glad you worked it out. If my answer helped you figure it out, you might want to accept it / upvote it. Or else you add an answer of your own that can help others in the same situation (after all, that's what stack overflow's about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for Maven projects. To make your project work with maven you'll have to follow that structure. Just as well you'll have to setup a pom.xml to create your .war file and so on.

For your 404: All web-resources are now in src/main/webapp. You'll need to add that as source folder as well (together with src/main/java) to have it picked up correctly for eclipse build as well.

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see my structure looks totally different than in your link. Do i have to create all those folders now and copy all the files manually? That would be a complete mess, i guess. Is there any way to remove all the changes made by maven and return to the status before?

Comment: You're not *that* far off. You need src/main/java and put your com/* in there and you'd be good to go I think. After that edit your source folders in eclipse. Remove src/ and then add subfolders src/main/webapp and src/main/java. Run mvn install and you should be back to normal